# Understanding png output settings

Tags: r, png, plot

I don't understand how I can arrange a plot to fill an image of a certain pixel size, with a specific font-size and a small margin. Here is an example plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

a <-c(1:10); b <- c(1:10)
p <- qplot(a,b)
outPath = "D:/Scratch/"

# 1
png(paste(outPath, '1.png', sep=''), height=400, width=400, res = 120, units = 'px')
print(p); dev.off()
```

[image]

```
# 2
png(paste(outPath, '2.png', sep=''), pointsize = 20,height=400, width=400, res = 120, units = 'px')
print(p); dev.off()
```

[image]

```
# 3
png(paste(outPath, '3.png', sep=''), height=400, width=400, res = 250, units = 'px')
print(p); dev.off()
```

[image]

I'm less concerned about the resolution of the image, but I want the font size to be large, in proportion to the overall image (similar to plot #3). The argument `pointsize` does not appear to result in any font size changes.I also want the border to be minimized. At the moment, if I use the settings on #3 there is a much larger space around the plot, when compared to the other images. How can I have a plot that has large font, with a small margin?

Comment: I always use ggsave for saving, works like a charm.

Comment: Perhaps I should have illustrated my problem using a different package. I'm using `rasterVis` to produce plots of spatial data, but I thought the general problem might be similar and `ggplot` is easier to use to explain the problem. I realize now that it is more package specific.

Answer (score 2):

Controlling most aspects of the saved image will be more easily accomplished on the `ggplot2` side of things (compared to playing with `png()` settings).

Within `ggplot2`, `opts()` can be used to control both the font size, and the widths of figure margins.

Here's an example:

```
p <- qplot(a,b) +
opts(plot.margin = unit(rep(0,4), "lines"),
     axis.title.x = theme_text(size=20),
     axis.title.y = theme_text(size=20))

png('1.png', height=400, width=400, res = 120, units = 'px')
print(p); dev.off()
```

[image]